# programming in C involving strings

Tags: c, string

1.actually I want to first give a number N (no. of strings I want to enter) as an input then in next line a string using gets().But when I press enter then the no. of strings I could enter is N-1.I tried using printf("\n") but it didn't work.Please anyone could help me in this.eg:

```
    //code
    int N,i,arr[N]; 
    char str[50];
    scanf("%d",&N) //no. of strings required
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      gets(str);
       arr[i]=strlen(a);
     }
     for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     {
      printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
     }
```

i want to enter my input to be like this:

```
    2  //no. of strings
    ABCFD //string 1
    ASWD //string 2
    //But actually what i am getting using printf("\n")
```

and output:

```
    5
    4
```

but what i am getting:

```
    2
    //blank space 
    ASWD //string 2
```

and output

```
    0
    4
```

Comment: Post your code so we can look at it.

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't be disappointed when your question is downvoted. Keep in mind that others who want to answer require sufficient information. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details. In this case provide a minimal code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After entering a value for `N` there remains a `newline` in the input buffer, which is accepted by the following `gets` as a blank input. In any case `gets` is a deprecated function: please use `fgets` such as like this. I've printed each entry to show there is a `newline` at the end of each, and removed that newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int N, i; 
    char str[50];
    printf("Enter number of cases\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &N);                                 // read newline too, but discard
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter string\n");
        if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL)
            return 1;
        printf("Shows newline >>%s<<\n", str);          // show that newline is retained
        str [ strcspn(str, "\r\n") ] = 0;               // remove trailing newline
        printf("After removal >>%s<<\n", str);          // show that newline was removed
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
Enter number of cases
2

Enter string
one
Shows newline >>one
<<
After removal >>one<<

Enter string
two
Shows newline >>two
<<
After removal >>two<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it --

```
int lineNumbers;
scanf("%d", &lineNumbers);
char **linesOfString = (char**) malloc(lineNumbers * sizeof(char *));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < lineNumbers; i++) {
    fflush(stdin);
    linesOfString[i] = (char *) malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", linesOfString[i]);
}
for(i = 0; i < lineNumbers; i++) {
    printf("%s", linesOfString[i]);
}
free(linesOfString);

return 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are not getting the number of strings expected, is this correct?

If this is the case, look at your looping code.

The most likely newbie mistake is with indexing.  Arrays in C are 0 indexed.

This means that if you have int test[3], the indexes of test will be 0, 1, and 2.  This means that the highest index WILL be N-1.

So, make sure that the first string you are accepting is being placed into index 0, and not index 1.